# django - how to replace startElement in XML?

Tags: python, xml, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to generate a custom HTML and I have a value I want to pass into xml.startElement (or root if you're thinking in generic terms).  How do I go about doing this?

I'm currently using django rest framework a class view and a custom renderer -

This is the beginning of the renderer -

```
class TESTRenderer(renderers.BaseRenderer):

    media_type = 'application/xml'
    format = 'xml'
    charset = 'utf-8'

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        """
        Renders *obj* into serialized XML.
        """

        if data is None:
            return ''

        stream = StringIO()

        xml = SimplerXMLGenerator(stream, self.charset)
        xml.startDocument()
        xml.startElement(header.data, {})
```

So as you can see I'm trying to pass a variable called header into the xml.startElement

Here's the view where that data lies -

```
class TestDetail(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a snippet instance.
    """
    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):

        jobmst_name = queryset1
        nodmst_alias = queryset2
        sysval_integer = queryset3
        mst = queryset4
        dtl = queryset5     
        dep = queryset6
        trg = queryset7

        name = str(jobmst_name)
        master = str(nodmst_alias)
        dbversion = str(sysval_integer)
        header = 'job id="%s" name="%s" master="%s" dbversion="%s" xmlversion="1"' % (pk, name, master, dbversion)

        jobmststring = JobmstSerializer(mst)
        jobdtlstring = JobdtlSerializer(dtl)
        jobdepstring = JobdepSerializer(dep, many=True)
        trgjobstring = TrgjobSerializer(trg, many=True)

        jobmst_serialized = {'jobmst': jobmststring.data}
        jobdtl_serialized = {'jobdtl': jobdtlstring.data}
        jobdep_serialized = [{'jobdep':item} for item in jobdepstring.data]
        trgjob_serialized = [{'trgjob':item} for item in trgjobstring.data]

        jobgroup = header, jobmst_serialized, jobdtl_serialized, jobdep_serialized, trgjob_serialized

        return TestResponse(jobgroup)
```

The response it's using is here -

```
class TestResponse(HttpResponse):
    """
    An HttpResponse that renders its content into XML.
    """
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = TESTRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/xml'
        super(TestResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)
```

Is there something I'm missing with the TestDetail where I should separate the header from the data?

maybe like this?

```
return TestResponse (header, jobgroup)
```

and then alter TestResponse to include?

```
def __init__(self, header, data, **kwargs):
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python/django. but it seems the "Value" you are talking about are actually attributes you want to assign to the element node. I posted the same on your /r/django thread about this.